# Can you set an IP address to a top level domain?

Tags: dns, top-level-domains, a-record

I was wondering if you could set a DNS (A type) that points a top-level domain to an IP address (e.g. `https://com` points to an 8.8.8.8). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no.

In the structure of the DNS hierachy there is nothing preventing this behaviour - however in order to do it you need control over the tld.

You can do this in a hosts file if you run your own dns, but you cant do it globally for .com as you dont own it.  If you have a lot of money you could get a vanity tld and do this for that tld.

Thinking of this there is one common place this fairly universally happens - but not through DNS - "localhost" is typically bound to 127.0.0.1 using a hosts file.

Comment: Owning a top level domain does cost "a lot of money."  To put a number on it, it would be north of $100,000 (USD) just for the application fee.  Plus you have to meet a whole host of ICANN requirements.  See [Can I create a top level TLD? (.michael for instance)](https://serverfault.com/questions/243316/can-i-create-a-top-level-tld-michael-for-instance) on ServerFault.

Comment: Even if you did own a TLD, there might be ICANN rules against resolving the top level domain to an IP address.   I'm not aware of any top level domain (including the vanity ones) that resolves to an IP address currently.  I'd think that if it were allowed, some TLD would be doing it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller "there might be ICANN rules against resolving the top level domain to an IP address" There is indeed, right into the agreement between ICANN and registries. Of course that doesn't apply to ccTLDs, with a dozen of them doing it...

Answer (score 3):

It is possible (if you control the TLD obviously), and it exists, but only in non ICANN controlled TLDs, which are gTLDs.

For gTLDs, ICANN - to block any new instance of the past SiteFinder issue - disallows records that are basically not `NS`, and `A`/`AAAA` only for glues needed, and related maintenance ones (DNSSEC). In theory that would even prohibit generic `TXT` records.

In ccTLDs, everything is possible, because technically an `A` record at apex is nothing special.
I touched it already at my own answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49022087/6368697
but in short:

- it exists, `https://dk/` being a widely known example that does not seem to work anymore right now, but you can try `https://ai/` for example because `dig ai. A +short` returns `209.59.119.34`
- Wikipedia has a list of other examples (I need to find it again)
- See [RFC 7085 "Top-Level Domains That Are Already Dotless"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7085) (December 2013) for a listing of all "dotless" cases (at that time), such as .DK, but they were 15 more. And even more if you count replies for `MX` DNS type.
- SAC-053 from ICANN gives the reasoning against "dotless" domains (explaining they may fail to work because of broken applications/configurations basically)
- ICANN contracts with registry at https://newgtlds.icann.org/sites/default/files/agreements/agreement-approved-31jul17-en.html#exhibitA.1 specifically list which records and content can appear at apex; note how `A` and `AAAA` are missing from the list except indirectly with the mention of "glues"

Comment: `https://dk/ ` doesn't work for me.   `dig dk.` doesn't give an A record with an IP address for me.

Comment: When I entered `https://dk/` it didn't resolve to an IP address. I assume I'm just using the wrong DNS servers for this though.

Comment: So they removed that "feature" recently then, let me edit the answer with another example. Do note however that browsers do all kind of funky stuff with names, and some can interpret "short" names as keywords and do a search or like in the past some automatically added `.com` at the end in some cases.